# How to append additional text with existing html content in android?

Tags: android, webview, web

I am Developing an application.In which i am appending a text to existing text which is stored in .html file, the location for the .html file is in my application's "assets" folder. I know how to load html with URL but my problem is to append the text.
following is my java code

```
public class LoadWeb extends Activity {
    WebView wv;
    private Handler handler = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        handler = new Handler();  
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(this, "contactSupport");
        wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
       // String title=wv.getTitle();
    // Log.e("nitin", "msg"+title);


        setTheme(Color.CYAN);
       // wv.setInitialScale(100);




        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/style.html");


        }
    void loadTime() {
        String TESTSTRING = "'<div style='color:blue; border:1px solid red;'>YO!</div>'"; 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("mitiiiiiii", ""+TESTSTRING);
        wv.loadUrl("javascript:appendText("+TESTSTRING+")"); 

    }


    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


            return(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            loadTime();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    }
    public String deleteContact(final String contactId){  
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),contactId ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         handler.post(new Runnable() {  
              public void run() {  
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),contactId ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }  
            }); 

        Log.i("nitin"      ,""+contactId);
        return "http://google.com";
    }

}
```

and following is my javascript code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var extraStr;
function appendText(extraStr) {

     document.getElementById('question')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById('question')[0].innerHTML + extraStr;
     contactSupport.deleteContact();
 }  

function getUsed()
{
    var total = "";
    $(".boxWord.boxWordUsed").each(function (i){ total = total + this.getAttribute('index_no') + ":"; });
    return total;
}


</script>
<link href="style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="question" class='question' >
</div>
```

Can any body tell me why it is not working

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Appending to HTML (concatenation) as String joining is not a good solution, but you can try this approach which will ensure that the html document's sanctity is not broken. Since you have the HTML document with you, it signifies you have control over that document and hence you should be able to do this which I am mentioning below.

1) Create a function in HTML

```
 function appendText(extraStr) {
     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML =     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML + extraStr;
 }
```

2) On WebView load call this function

```
 myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:appendText('extra text or html here')");
```

3) Don't forget to add this

```
 myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Sir It will permanently change my html or temporarily please reply I am not very much experienced in JavaScript.Because I want to change It Dynamically

Comment: It will be temporary, it won't change your base HTML. But yes the function I showed you on top will be there in your html permanently. If you don't want that you can still call the actual part of the function directly from java, without adding it.

Comment: when I should call this function after loading webview I am doing like this wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/style.html");
wv.loadUrl("javascript:appendText("+TESTSTRING+")"); but this is not working. please suggest me right method

Comment: Not immediately after loading, it won't work. You have do it on WebView finished loading.  See this link for onPageFinished  function http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: bro it is not working I have called it on onpagefinished but it is not working

Comment: ok, let debug it. Write code to allow alerts from your webview. See this link (comment 12) http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=752 for this purpose. Once you have setup the alert. Inside function appendText(), write alert('1'); and also alert(document.getElementsByTagName('body').length); and see what happens. We will go to next step from here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3722/discussion-between-nitin-and-rahul-choudhary)

Comment: Sir can you please check my code I have debug it but the function appendText(extraStr) is not called

Comment: The problem is this line document.getElementById('question')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById('question')[0].innerHTML + extraStr; getElementsByTagName returns an array and hence [0] but getElementById returns the element directly. Remove [0] from both the places and it shall work.