# how can webview use another page's javascript

Tags: android, webview

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.htmlview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new DemoJavaScriptInterface(),
      "demo"); mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
```

---

i know how to invoke a page's javascript,but if the page have no the js i need.if i can invoke a js that i write?

webview of android;

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to save your javascript code under asset directory of your eclipse IDE and run it.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't done this before, but this looks good for me: [How to append additional text with existing html content in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525196/how-to-append-additional-text-with-existing-html-content-in-android)

It says, after loading the page into your WebView, you can just execture JavaScript by calling
`myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('My JavaScript Call')");`

Answer (score 2):

So many way to call javascript in your web view

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:testEcho('Hello World!')");
```

or

```
public void run(final String scriptSrc) { 
    webView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + scriptSrc); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

or

```
public void run(final String scriptSrc) { 
    webView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + scriptSrc); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview) question to help me achieve this task for me.

You can also use  [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for call java script.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   @Override
  public void onPageFinished (WebView webView, String url)
  {


         webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('login_player').value='"+username+"';javascript:document.getElementById('login_passwd').value = '"+Password+"';");
      }
     });
```

for more help u can also see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472839/using-javascript-in-android-webview) .