# Appending more views to a webview after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I have some items, let's say 50, which are in HTML format. When the application starts I'm showing the first 10 items in a webview. After the user scrolls down to the 10th item I want to load the next 10 items.

Can anybody suggest me how to do achieve this. I've searched for this and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525196/how-to-append-additional-text-with-existing-html-content-in-android) however it didn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

This is more look like facebook feed loading.But like in facebook we can use endless apdapter.But here the problem is i want to load items in a webview.Please give me some idea,how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Struggling and searching a lot I got this answer please check.

So it will append the new document in the Html part with id question with the new Data

function appendText(extraStr) {
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = document.getElementById('question').innerHTML + extraStr;
}